# Office.context.mailbox.item is null after selecting multiple items

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have a pinnable Outlook Web-addon.  If I select multiple items at once then the task pane shows an error telling me that task pane addons do not support multiple selection.  I then deselect all but one item and from now on when the event Office.EventType.ItemChanged fires Office.context.mailbox.item is null.

Is this a bug, do I need to do something to re-initialize after multiple items have been selected?

Comment: Which variant of application are you using Windows App, MAC App or Web App? What is the version? Can you share code snippet for repro?

Answer (score 0):

It was the web version but I think I have solved it.  It looks like the error was actually from when there were multiple selected (which makes sense) bit then the event stopped firing.

Anyway, I have put some more guards in an all seems well